# Limit of constant function

Tags: probability, limits, infinity

I was reading a proof using Markov Chains in a finite state space $E$. Denote $p_{ij}(n) = P(X_n = j | X_0 = i)$.

Since the state space is finite, then probability of landing somewhere in the state space after $n$ steps is $1$, that is :
$$\sum_{j\in E} p_{ij}(n) = 1 \qquad \forall n \in \mathbb N$$
The next line uses this to imply :
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{j\in E} p_{ij}(n) = 1$$
which seems logical but from a strict mathematical point of view, why is this true?

One could say that the function is strictly constant therefore the limit is invariant. Consider $f(x) = 1$, then clearly the limit is $1$ itself.
On the other hand consider the following function :
$$f(n) = I\bigg(\frac{1}{n} \ne 0\bigg)$$
where $I$ is the indicator function. Clearly $f(n) = 1$ for all non-zero integers so it's constant but $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n) = 0$.

So although $f(n)$ is constant, the limit isn't equal itself...

Question is how to prove the first limit is $1$? Also is there a problem in my example using the indicator function?

Comment: I think that's a very interesting question, and the indicator function went against my old ideas of a limit.  That is, if the limit of $f(n)$ is some constant $c$, then $f$ can get arbitrarily close to $c$ as we raise $n$.  But that's not the case for the indicator function.  We never get close to $0$.  However, wolfram gives this : https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+Piecewise%5B%7B%7B1%2Cnot+1%2Fn+%3D0%7D%2C%7B0%2C+1%2Fx+%3D+0%7D%7D%5D%2Cn+to+infinity.  That is, it evaluates this limit as 1.  I don't know why though...maybe because of the way of defining a limit I speak of.

Comment: @manuellafond: According to the definition of the limit, you should be able to get arbitrarily close to the limit but my function doesn't behave like this. Reason why I suspect there might be something wrong with it... Also I normally trust WA on solving ODE and integrals but not on that kind of stuff.